# sed or awk reformatting a line by copying part of it to the end of the line

Tags: awk, sed, python, csv, sqlite

I have a CSV file I wish to edit before importing it into a SQLITE DB.  It has thousands of lines in it and I want to copy part of the line and append it to the end with a pipe "|" so that it can easily delimited and imported into the DB.

The csv contains lines like:

```
989155126903533568|2018-04-25|14:52:14|GMT|report|"""Умственно отстал"" was checked -  http://steamcommunity.com/profiles/76561198402636850 …"|0|0|0|
989154874184085505|2018-04-25|14:51:14|GMT|report|"""Clavicus Vile"" was checked (8 reports) -  http://steamcommunity.com/profiles/76561198006267103 …"|0|0|0|
989154622890823685|2018-04-25|14:50:14|GMT|report|"""~TAKA~"" was checked (3 reports) -  http://steamcommunity.com/profiles/76561198161608591 …"|0|0|0|
```

I want to copy the 765 number and add it to the end of the line like the below:

```
989154622890823685|2018-04-25|14:50:14|GMT|report|"""~TAKA~"" was checked (3 reports) -  http://steamcommunity.com/profiles/76561198161608591 …"|0|0|0|76561198161608591
```

I'd like to do this for every line in the csv.  So maybe a for loop would be required.  I'm not sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**`sed`** solution:

```
sed -E 's/.*\/profiles\/([0-9]+).*/&\1/' file.csv
```

Sample output:

```
989155126903533568|2018-04-25|14:52:14|GMT|report|"""Умственно отстал"" was checked -  http://steamcommunity.com/profiles/76561198402636850 …"|0|0|0|76561198402636850
989154874184085505|2018-04-25|14:51:14|GMT|report|"""Clavicus Vile"" was checked (8 reports) -  http://steamcommunity.com/profiles/76561198006267103 …"|0|0|0|76561198006267103
989154622890823685|2018-04-25|14:50:14|GMT|report|"""~TAKA~"" was checked (3 reports) -  http://steamcommunity.com/profiles/76561198161608591 …"|0|0|0|76561198161608591
```

Comment: This works great.  Especially as it removes the ... from the end of the number.  Thanks for the answer

Comment: @Blindy Hitting "accept answer" is the preferred way to say "thank you".

Answer (score 0):

```
$ sed -E 'h;s/.*(http[^ ]*).*/\1/;s/.*\///;H;x;s/\n//' file
989155126903533568|2018-04-25|14:52:14|GMT|report|"""Умственно отстал"" was checked -  http://steamcommunity.com/profiles/76561198402636850 …"|0|0|0|76561198402636850
989154874184085505|2018-04-25|14:51:14|GMT|report|"""Clavicus Vile"" was checked (8 reports) -  http://steamcommunity.com/profiles/76561198006267103 …"|0|0|0|76561198006267103
989154622890823685|2018-04-25|14:50:14|GMT|report|"""~TAKA~"" was checked (3 reports) -  http://steamcommunity.com/profiles/76561198161608591 …"|0|0|0|76561198161608591
```

The `sed` script with annotations:

```
h                        # save a copy of the current line in the "hold space"
s/.*(http[^ ]*).*/\1/    # remove everything but the URL
s/.*\///                 # trim the URL so that only the last bit (the number) is left
H                        # add that last bit to the "hold space" (with a newline in-between)
x                        # swap the "hold space" and the "pattern space"
s/\n//                   # delete that inserted newline
                         # (implicit print at the end)
```

This assumes that the URL is always the *only* URL on the line and that it is *always* delimited by a space character.

Answer (score 0):

With `awk`:

```
awk -F'["/]' '{print $0$(NF-1)}' infile > outfile
```

`print` the whole line `$0` and second last field `$(NF-1)` where field separator `-F` is either set `'[...]'` of quote `"` or slash `/` from `infile` and save the result into `outfile`.